# Embed JQuery library in HTML file

Tags: html, jquery

I have a script running to pull data from a database and send a report via email to the interested stakeholders. I have the data being compiled into a table and sent out as an HTML file. I recently added some jQuery to allow for the filtering of the data, and it works great when using a computer to bring up the HTML file. However when the file is opened in the Outlook app on a phone, the jQuery isn’t working at all. I believe this is because it is unable to access the CDN to pull down the jQuery libraries. Is there a way to add the jQuery libraries into the HTML header to enable my jQuery code to function?

I have tried downloading the compressed jQuery library and pasted the contents in a script tag in the HTML header. I still have no functionality of my jQuery code.

Comment: Email clients are quite different than web browsers. I think most don't allow any javascript to run.

Comment: Thank you, I imagine this is what the issue is.